# How should try-catch be used with multiple event handlers?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say we have a function that attaches a bunch of event handlers. I noticed a try-catch around all of them catches what's inside the event functions. Should it be done like this?

```
function attachHandlers() {
    try {
        network.on('event1', async (evt) => {
            ...
        });

        network.on('event2', async (evt) => {
            ...
        });
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
  }
```

Or try-catch inside each handler separately?

```
  function attachHandlers() {
    network.on('event1', async (evt) => {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });

    network.on('event2', async (evt) => {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: The first one won’t catch errors that are thrown inside the event handlers.

Comment: `try/catch` around the event handlers will only catch if there's an error while attaching to them.  It won't catch if there's an error when the functions are executed.  For that you'd need it inside, like the 2nd example.

Comment: I swore I tried it and i did, but must have made a mistake somewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, your try/catch surrounding the attachements of the listeners won't catch errors thrown inside the handlers.

If you wanted to know when an error is thrown by the handlers, you could listen to the `error` event on the `window` object.

If you wanted to catch them, you could use `preventDefault` on the `errorEvent` in that errorHandler.

**EDIT** : for some reason, the snippet below doesn't "catch" the error and it ends up being unCaught in the console. I tested it on chrome and it works.

```js
const myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

myBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("handler 1");
  throw "Error in handler1";

});

myBtn.addEventListener("click", function(error) {
  console.log("handler 2");
  throw "Error in handler2";
});

window.addEventListener("error", function (error) {
    error.preventDefault();
    console.error("Error caught");
    return false;
});
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Click</button>
```